# Differentiation and continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative, dense-subspaces

I would like to find a proof on the following proposition.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and $O$ an open set of $X$ and $\overset{\sim}{X}$ be a dense subspace e of $X$. Let $F : O \to Y$ be a continuous application. We suppose that $ \forall x \in \overset{\sim}{X} \cap O$ there exists a linear application $L : X\to Y$ such that :

$$\forall v \in \overset{\sim}{X},\; \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{F(x+tv)-F(x)}{t}=L(x)v $$

If the application $x \to L(x)$ is continuous on $\overset{\sim}{X} \cap O$ then $F \in C^1(O)$ and $DF(x) = L(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This looks like a definition to me. In what terms should this proof you wish for be?

Comment: I read a document on gateaux and frechet differentiability and there was this proposition with the remark : "To prove that a function F is $C^1$ we can prove that it's gateaux differentiable and that $D_G F$ is continuous. This proposition helps us to prove that  a function is $C^1$". But there was no proof.

Comment: You probably want $L(x):X\to Y$ to be continuous and the continuity of $O\to L(X,Y)$, $x\mapsto L(x)$ where $L(X,Y)$ is endowed with the operator norm.